# Ember Services - Create default settings for application

Tags: ember.js

My app has a lot of reports, and I have **dateBegin** and **dateEnd** in all of then.

The desired behaviour is:

- app first load, **dateBegin** = month begin (jun-01) / **dateEnd** = today (jun-11)
- when user change dates (let's say to mai-01 / mai-31), all controllers get the new dates

The code that I have now:

```js
// app/services/defaults.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  init: function () {
    this._super();
    var dateEnd = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var dateBegin = moment().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    
    if (!this.get('dateEnd')) { this.set('dateEnd', dateEnd); }
    if (!this.get('dateBegin')) { this.set('dateBegin', dateBegin }
  }
});
```

```js
// app/components/select-dates-in-reports.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  defaults: Ember.inject.service(),

  displayDateBegin: null,
  displayDateEnd: null,
  dateBegin: Ember.computed.alias('defaults.dateBegin'),
  dateEnd: Ember.computed.alias('defaults.dateEnd'),

  setInitialParams: Ember.on('init', function () {
    this.set('displayDateBegin', this.get('dateBegin'));
    this.set('displayDateEnd', this.get('dateEnd'));
  }),

  actions: {
    chooseParams: function () {
      this.set('dateBegin', this.get('displayDateBegin'));
      this.set('dateEnd', this.get('displayDateEnd'));
    }
  }
});
```

```js
// app/mixins/query-params-for-reports.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  queryParams: ['dateBegin', 'dateEnd'],

  defaults: Ember.inject.service(),

  dateBegin: Ember.computed.alias('defaults.dateBegin'),
  dateEnd: Ember.computed.alias('defaults.dateEnd')
});
```

```js
// app/mixins/routes-query-params-for-reports.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  queryParams: {
    dateBegin: {
      refreshModel: true
    },
    dateEnd: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },

  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find(this.get('modelName'),
      {
        dateBegin: params.dateBegin,
        dateEnd: params.dateEnd
      }
    );
  }
});
```

It works as desired just after each controller is initialized:

- user enter the app, and visit controller1. **dateBegin** = jun-01 / **dateEnd** = jun-11
- on the same controller1, user change dates to **dateBegin** = mai-01 / **dateEnd** = mai-31
- user visit controller2. **Here is the Problem**. The dates are set to **dateBegin** = jun-01 / **dateEnd** = jun-11
- on the same controller2, user change dates to **dateBegin** = apr-01 / **dateEnd** = apr-30
- user visit controller1 **again**. **Now it works**. The dates are set to **dateBegin** = apr-01 / **dateEnd** = apr-30

I tried all I could find over the net.
Create Initializers, used localStorage, etc. Nothing works.

Can anyone helps me??
thanks!

Comment: controllers 1,2 are from different routes? and both extend Ember.Controller with query-params-for-reports mixin?

Comment: I think problem is in using same queryParams for different controllers with different routes. How your router file looks like?

Comment: Hi, Yes, they are different routes. Route1/Controller1, Route2/Controller2.

Comment: I added another snippet with the route mixim for query params (I have to define modelName on each route). I just import this mixins on all routes / controllers that I want to filter by date.

Answer (score 0):

[Ember Dependency Injection to the rescue!](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/)

You can create a singleton object to hold the dates:

```
App.SelectedDates = Ember.Object.extend({
  dateBegin: null,
  dateEnd: null // or whatever value you want...
});
```

Then, inject that object into ALL controllers like this:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'register-global-dates',
  initialize: function(container,app) {
    app.register('my:globalDate', App.SelectedDates.create(), {
      singleton: true,
      instantiate: false
    });
    app.inject('controller', 'dateglobal', 'my:globalDate');
  }
});
```

Now, in your controller(s), you can do this:

```
this.dateglobal.set('dateBegin', '2015/01/12');
```

It's the same object in all controllers.

I hope I am understanding your problem correctly and that this is the solution...

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks... but it didn't work.
I'm already using injections, as introduced in [version 1.10](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_injected-properties).
It seems that controllers already have the initial property on boot, and don't change until you instantiate it.